# Recursion and anonymous functions in elixir

Tags: recursion, anonymous-function, elixir

I'm trying to define an anonymous function to do a dot product, I can code this as a private function without any problem but I am struggling with the anonymous function syntax.
I know I could implement this differently but I am trying to understand how to define anonymous functions with pattern matching and recursion.
This is my current implementation

```
dot = fn
  [i|input],[w|weights], acc -> dot.(input,weights,i*w+acc)
  [],[bias],acc -> acc + bias
end
```

And I get this error on compile:

```
function dot/0 undefined
```

Any hints? Is this just not possible?

Comment: // , Excellent question, Batou99. Do you know if there's anything about this, specifically, in the Elixir documentation? Might be a good candidate for the FAQ page.

Comment: Not as far as I know. But José Valim added some comment about this may be changing due to changes in Erlang 17, we are now at Erlang 18 so this definitely may have changed already.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not possible to recur on anonymous functions in Elixir.

Erlang 17 (currently a release candidate) adds this possibility to Erlang and we plan to leverage it soon. Right now, the best approach is to define a module function and pass it around:

```
def neural_bias([i|input],[w|weights], acc) do
  neural(input,weights,i*w+acc)
end

def neural_bias([], [bias], acc) do
  acc + bias
end
```

And then:

```
&neural_bias/3
```

Comment: Then I think I prefer using private functions with defp.

Comment: Yup. It was just an example, it will also work as a private function.

Comment: Does elixir now support recursing anonymous functions?

Comment: Not yet, we had plans but we couldn't agree on a syntax so it has been postponed to after 1.0.

Comment: @JoséValim where could we follow debates about this subject ?

Comment: The elixir-lang-core mailing list is where those discussions happen. It has become quite low-volume though after 1.0 was out.

Comment: As noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829932/1276737) it is possible to define a recursive function using only anonymous function using the excellent fix point combinator (Y combinator). Though I guess the asker was expecting first class language support without having to use `Y`.

Comment: @JoséValim Has this been added yet?

Comment: From what I know it's still not here

Comment: how is this still not a thing

Answer (score 37):

The less formal but still acceptable approach is:

```
factorial = fn
  (0,_) -> 1
  (1,_) -> 1
  (n, fun) -> n * fun.(n - 1, fun)
end
```

You call it with `factorial.(6, factorial) # 720`

Comment: That's kind of like PHP's &referencing style.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a fixed (Y) combinator:

```
fix = fn f -> 
    (fn z ->
        z.(z)
    end).(fn x -> 
        f.(fn y -> (x.(x)).(y) end)
    end)
end
```

Here's how you use it:

```
factorial = fn factorial ->
    fn
        0 -> 0
        1 -> 1
        number -> number * factorial.(number - 1)
    end
end

fix.(factorial).(6) # 720
```

Only works with functions that recurse with 1 argument. Elixir doesn't have variable arguments. To support multiple arguments, you'll need to add more arguments than the single `y` like: `f.(fn a,b -> (x.(x)).(a,b) end)`.

Comment: I would call the original function `factorial_stub` and `factorial = fix.(factorial_stub)`. Simple change but makes it a little clearer to first timers IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a module-function called `fix`, and use it later to define `dot` (and any other recursing anonymous function):

```
defmodule A do
    def fix(f, x) do
      f.(fn(x) -> fix(f, x) end, x)
    end

    def fix2(f, x, y) do
      f.(fn(x, y) -> fix2(f, x, y) end, x, y)
    end
end

dot = fn(x, y) ->
    A.fix2(fn
          dot, [i|input],[w|weights], acc -> dot.(input,weights,i*w+acc)
          dot, [],[bias],acc -> acc + bias
    end, x, y)
end
```

Comment: Is this the y-combinator?

Comment: Essentially, a fixed-point combinator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator

Comment: I see that there is fix1 and fix2, can there be a single fix or any number of arguments?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not using Elixir anymore, and it has changed a lot since I stopped. You should open a new question if you'd like to get an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing on @hamiltop answer, if you don't to always pass the fn yourself during calls, you can then wrap it:

```
factorial_rec = fn
  (0,_) -> 1
  (1,_) -> 1
  (n, fun) -> n * fun.(n - 1, fun)
end

factorial = fn n ->
  factorial_rec.(n, factorial_rec)
end
```

So you can call it as `factorial.(6)`