# Named anonymous functions in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Does Elixir support named anonymous functions similar to Clojure?
For example, I want to do something like this:

```
fib_fun = fn fib n -> if n <= 1 do 1 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) end end
```

so that I can recursively call the anonymous function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Elixir doesn't support recursion in anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21983413/1533054)**, but you can implement it as a Y-Combinator with [guard clauses](https://elixirforum.com/t/anonymous-functions-with-multiple-body/3721) like this:

```
fib = fn x ->
  fun = fn
    (n, _) when n <= 1 -> 1
    (n, fun) -> fun.(n-1, fun) + fun.(n-2, fun)
  end

  fun.(x, fun)
end
```

and call it like usual:

```
fib.(5)
#=> 8
```

---

So it's a better idea to just write it as a normal method inside a module (which would also look much more cleaner):

```
defmodule Fibonacci do
  def get(n) when n <= 1, do: 1
  def get(n), do: get(n-1) + get(n-2)
end
```